# Eclipse index cache location in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

I have little space in my partition and I've indexed a large project via Eclipse IDE that has generated a large amount of cache which occupies about 800MB of disk space.I couldn't find anything about that in `~/.eclipse` or `~/.cache/Eclipse` or `~/.p2` and also **[Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/)** didn't me help to find that(looks like a needle in the haystack because I have lots of directories with different sizes).

So I just want to know where does Eclipse store those index caches?

Comment: It will be in the workspace .metadata somewhere, exactly where depends on what programming language you are using.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes it is.Thanks.You can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caches are part of the workspace .metadata.

For Java the indices are in the .plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core directory in the metadata.